# Illegal Instruction 4 :(

Tags: c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char getInput[20];
    scanf("%s", getInput);
    char append[] = "word";
    printf("%s\n", strcat(append, getInput));
    return 0;
}
```

Why does this give me illegal instruction 4

Comment: You are overflowing stack when writing past the end of  `append`

Comment: `char append[] = "word";` --> `char append[100] = "word";`

Comment: You urgently need to enable more compiler warnings, like `-Wall`, to catch simple mistakes.

Comment: @tadman Will it help in this case?

Comment: Well it will at least complain as a result of no `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: `append` has room for 5 characters. You're appending to it and blowing up when you write to memory you don't own.

Comment: One *neat* thing about the code is the way you pass the return value from `strcat` to `printf`. Nice, but one more criticism is that `scanf("%s", getInput);` can also cause buffer overflow, instead use `scanf("%19s", getInput);`

Comment: @user3386109 et al this cleared up all issues thank you vm. I still have a lot to learn about the memory capabilities and best practices for C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer to use fgets into fixed buffer, and ensure that you leave room for null-terminator (and check that input not truncated).

Or, you can use scanf into fixed buffer, and you can use clever trick to ensure you do not overflow fixed buffer. Or you can use '%as' flag (if your compiler supports it).

*Note that when you use dynamic allocation, you need to cleanup after yourself. This is why so many folks prefer garbage collected languages that perform memory cleanup/housekeeping for you.*

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char*
checkin(char* p) {
    if( !p ) return(p);
    if (0 == sizeof(p) ) {
        printf("error: read empty!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    int plen = strlen(p);
    if ('\n' != p[plen - 1]) {
        printf("error: input overflow (too long)!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    return(p);
}
char*
wrap(char* p) {
    char append[] = "word";
    printf("%s%s\n",append,p);
    char* combined = malloc(strlen(append)+strlen(p)+1);
    strcpy(combined,append);
    strcat(combined,p);
    printf("%s\n",combined);
    return(combined);
}
// use fixed size buffer, fgets
char*
getstuff() {
    char line[666];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line)-1, stdin);
    if( NULL == checkin(line) ) return NULL;
    char* combined = wrap(line);
    return combined;
}
// use fixed size buffer, dynamic scanf
char*
getstuff2() {
    char line[666];
    // dynamically build scanf fmt to specify input width
    char scanfmt[32];
    sprintf(scanfmt,"%%%lds",sizeof(line));
    scanf(scanfmt,line);
    char* combined = wrap(line);
    return(combined);
}
// use dynamic scanf read
char*
getstuff3() {
/* does your compiler support '%as' flag?
    // use scanf to automagically malloc enough space
    char *aline = NULL;
    scanf("%as",&aline);
    char* combined = wrap(aline);
    free(aline);
    return(combined);
 */
    return(NULL);
}
int
main() {
    char* stuff = getstuff();
    if( NULL != stuff ) printf("got:%s\n",stuff);
    free(stuff); stuff = NULL;
    char* stuff2 = getstuff2();
    if( NULL != stuff2 ) printf("got:%s\n",stuff2);
    free(stuff2); stuff2 = NULL;
    char* stuff3 = getstuff3();
    if( NULL != stuff3 ) printf("got:%s\n",stuff3);
    free(stuff3); stuff3 = NULL;
}
```

*There are many ways to skin a cat, I prefer #37, crazy-glue and a toothbrush!*